# How to configure Angular to use Firebird with Webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, firebird

How to correct way to implement the Firebird with Webpack on one simple Angular component?
I read some posts that "require" has been discouraged?

The package used is this https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebird

I already installed webpack

```
npm install --save-dev @types/webpack-env
```

And updating my tsconfig.json with the following under compilerOptions:

```
"types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ]
```

Could someone help me with the syntax and fix this code snippet below

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
//discouraged var fb = require ('firebird');

@Component ({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'project01';
  constructor () {
    var con = fb.createConnection();
    con.connectSync ('d:/data_base.FDB', 'SYSDBA', 'masterkey', '');

    var resfb = con.querySync ("select vendors.name_vendor from vendors");
    var rows = resfb.fetchSync ("all", true);
    con.commitSync ();
    console.log (sys.inspect (rows));
  }
}
```

For those who want to check the versions of the current libraries in my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mOS",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "firebird": "^0.1.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.6",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.39",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.15.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Do you get errors? If so, what are those errors? If something else happens (or does not happen), please describe your expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If i import it like this "import * as firebd from 'node_modules / firebird';"

[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/firebird/firebird.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './build/Release/binding' in 'D:\ProjetosApps\mOS\node_modules\firebird'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/firebird/firebird.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\ProjetosApps\mOS\node_modules\firebird'

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details, don't add them in comments.

Comment: Also, I don't know anything about Angular, but isn't Angular browser-side? If so, you can't use the Firebird node.js driver, as that is intended for server-side use through node.js.